How to import user attributes(like firstName, lastName and email) from keycloak to alfresco-content-service?
After login from external IDp, user attributes are reflecting in keycloak but in alfresco only principal attribute is imported, is there any way to import these attributes like firstName, lastName and email to alfresco from keycloak directly without using ldap ?
Any specific property to mention in share-config-custom.xml or alfresco-global.properties ?

I have working solution for Alfresco Community, not Enterprise, so there can be some more simple solution.
In Alfresco Community you can configure in alfresco-global.properties directly only these attributes:
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationAttributeName=department

Values after = is taken from AD.
If you want more attributes you need overwrite common-ldap-context.xml.
In default it is this file:
https://github.com/AlfrescoArchive/alfresco-repository/blob/master/src/main/resources/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/common-ldap-context.xml
In been
<bean id="userRegistry" class="org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry">
and tag <property name="personAttributeMapping">

you can define you own properties, like this:
<entry key="cm:telephone">
     <value>${ldap.synchronization.userTelephoneAttributeName}</value>
<entry>

Entry key is taken from attributes of cm:person. Value is string what you will use in alfresco-global.properties.
File common-ldap-context.xml you need put into path on alfresco server (or container) tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/ldap1.
If this path (after classes) don't exist, create it. Then add to alfresco-global.properties line like this:
ldap.synchronization.userTelephoneAttributeName=telephoneNumber

Restart Alfresco and you have sync telephoneNumber.

Thanks for the solution
But is there any way we can directly import userAttributes from keycloak without using the LDAP ?
From external IDP to keycloak we can import these attributes via mappers but from keycloak to alfresco these attributes are not getting updated (only principal attribute getting updated)
